# Android Studio JAVADOC comment shortcode not working

Tags: android-studio

I am not sure what is wrong but the JAVADOC is not generating when I type `/**` and hit `ENTER`. However, this all works fine in PhpStorm, InteliJ, Pycharm etc.

Any idea, suggestion or help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried invalidated caches and restart ? which version are you using ?

Comment: I did, I am using `3.2.1`

Comment: check language and defaults section  -> Doc Comment section , May be there is no section for  /**

Comment: There is only `Languages & Frameworks` menu and under it nothing like `Doc Comment`

Comment: Oh it is under `Color Scheme > Language Defaults` but than what to check to fix?